# The maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[x]$ which contains ideal $I＝(x^2＋1)$ contains $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, localization

$$\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}=\left\{\frac{a}{b}\mid a,b\in\mathbb{Z},p\nmid b\right\}.$$

I want to show

the maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[x]$ which contains ideal $I=(x^2+1)$ contains $p$.

I found an ideal $(p,x^2+1)$. This is maximal and contains $I$, certainly, contains $p$.

But I don't know how to show every maximal ideal which contains $I$ contain $p$. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? Convince yourself the given ideal isn’t maximal, so a maximal one contains “something new”. Could that new element be another polynomial? If not, what possible $p$-integers could it be?

Comment: I'm sorry I made mistake. （p,x^2＋１）⊂（p,x,x^2＋１）＝J , so is not maximal. Then , is J maximal ? First of all, I may need to find some maximal ideal.

Comment: $J$ is not proper so it's not a problem. You are right that the ideal $I$ you wrote down is not always maximal (depending on $p$) but it's a little more complicated. First think about the hint.

Comment: Thank you, but what is p-integers? p adic integers? and what kind of something new? You mean something new maximal ideal which contains （x＾２＋１）？

Comment: The ideal $(p,x^2+1)$ is not necessarily maximal, e.g. for $p=2,5,...$.

Comment: The idea is to show that a maximal ideal which does not contain $p$ is principal, generated by an irreducible polynomial. Or $(x^2+1)$ is not maximal.

Comment: Do you mean all ideals of Z（p）[x] is maximal unless it does not contain p ? I have no ideal how to prove it . Could you give me hints? Thank you.

Comment: Did I say that? I don't think so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any maximal ideal containing $I$ will be the preimage of a maximal ideal  $J\subset\mathbb{Z}_p[i]$.  As $\mathbb{Z}_p[i]$ is not a field we know that $J\neq 0$.  Pick $\frac{a+ib}c\neq 0$ in $J$.  Then as $J$ is a proper ideal we have $p|a^2+b^2$.  By unique factorisation in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ we may write $$a+ib=m(u+iv)^s(u-iv)^t\qquad {\rm or}\qquad a+ib=mp^r,$$
where $m\in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $p\not\!|m\bar{m}$ and in the first case $u^2+v^2=p$ with $u,v\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Thus either $(u+iv)^s(u-iv)^t\in J \quad {\rm or}\quad p^r\in J$. As $J$ is prime we have either $u+iv\in J$ or $u-iv\in J$ or $p\in J$.  In all three cases $p\in J$.

---

Alternative proof which does not use unique factorisation in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$:

Any maximal ideal containing $I$ will be the preimage of a maximal ideal  $J\subset\mathbb{Z}_p[i]$.  As $\mathbb{Z}_p[i]$ is not a field we know that $J\neq 0$.  Pick $\frac{a+ib}c\neq 0$ in $J$, with $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}$.  Then $$\left(\frac{a+ib}c\right)\left(\frac{a-ib}c\right)=\left(\frac{a^2+b^2}{c^2}\right)\in J.$$

Write $a^2+b^2=mp^r$ for some $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $p\not\!|m$ and $r\geq 0$.  Then $\frac m{c^2} p^r \in J$, which is maximal hence prime.  Thus either $\frac m{c^2}\in J$ or $p\in J$.

However $\frac m{c^2}$ is invertible, so not in $J$, as $J$ is a proper ideal.  Thus $p\in J$.

Comment: if J is proper, why can we say p｜a^2＋b^2 ?

Comment: @bellow otherwise $\frac {a+ib}c$ would be invertible, with inverse $\frac{c(a-ib)}{a^2+b^2}$.

Comment: @bellow It occured to me that there is no need to use unique factorisation in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ if you are not familiar with it, so I have added a more elementary proof.  I left the original one up, in case it was good for you.